# Hbox location of GridPanels

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, gridpane, hbox

I am Trying to have an HBox with two GridPanels, a bigger one in the left and a smaller one in the right (starting at the end of the right side the scene) however I cannot manage to get them in the positions I want to. [This is how it looks right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHnh1.png) As you can see, the red GridPane is on top of the other one. The red panel should go all the wait to the right. 
Moreover, I would like them to stay in the same position even if some buttons or text are added to either one of the GridPanes.

Here is my code:

```
    //TEST BUTTONS PANEL
    testButtonPane = new GridPane();
    testButtonPane.setHgap(10); 
    testButtonPane.setVgap(9); 
    testButtonPane.setPadding(new Insets(140, 100, 0, 100));


    questionLabel = new Label("Question:");
    questionLabel.setPrefWidth(500.0);
    questionLabel.setPrefHeight(50.0);
    questionLabel.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 timesnewroman; -fx-base: #AE3522");

    testButtonPane.add(questionLabel,1,1);



    testButtonPane.add(backButton,1,10);
    backButton = new Button("BACK");
    backButton.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(sceneCreateTest));
    backButton.setPrefWidth(140.0);
    backButton.setPrefHeight(50.0);
    backButton.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 timesnewroman; -fx-base: #AE3522");

    testButtonPane.add(backButton,1,10);



    //SCORE PANEL
    scoreButtonPane = new GridPane();
    scoreButtonPane.setHgap(10); 
    scoreButtonPane.setVgap(9); 
    scoreButtonPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10));

    scoreButtonPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #AE3522;-fx-border-color: black");

    statusTitleLabel = new Label("STATUS");
    statusTitleLabel.setPrefWidth(160.0);
    statusTitleLabel.setPrefHeight(50.0);
    statusTitleLabel.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 timesnewroman; -fx-text-fill:black ;");

    scoreButtonPane.add(statusTitleLabel,1,1,2,1);

    scoreLabel = new Label("Score: ");
    scoreLabel.setPrefWidth(130.0);
    scoreLabel.setPrefHeight(50.0);
    scoreLabel.setStyle("-fx-font: 20 timesnewroman; -fx-text-fill:black ;");

    scoreButtonPane.add(scoreLabel,1,2);


    timerLabel = new Label("Time: ");
    timerLabel.setPrefWidth(130.0);
    timerLabel.setPrefHeight(50.0);
    timerLabel.setStyle("-fx-font: 20 timesnewroman; -fx-text-fill:black ;");

    scoreButtonPane.add(timerLabel,1,3);


    QInLabel = new Label("Question: ");
    QInLabel.setPrefWidth(130.0);
    QInLabel.setPrefHeight(50.0);
    QInLabel.setStyle("-fx-font: 20 timesnewroman; -fx-text-fill:black ;");

    scoreButtonPane.add(QInLabel,1,4);


    //Makes possible to have two panes in the same scene/layout
    HBox hBoxTest = new HBox();
    hBoxTest.setSpacing(10.0); 
    hBoxTest.setPadding(new Insets(140,10,50,10));
    hBoxTest.getChildren().addAll(testButtonPane, scoreButtonPane);
```

The test buttons panel should go in the left and the score panel is the red one and should go in the right. I hope you can help me. Thank you so much in advance. =)

Comment: Can you expand your code so that it is a [MCVE]? When I added the minimum amount to make this executable, it was laid out exactly as you said you wanted it. (So the problem is caused by code that you haven't posted.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, you were actually right, when I run again it worked, so apparently the bug is fixed already.